# Excel - Split one columns values into 2 columns, split on every 2nd row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this data set which i want to split into two columns using a formula.
I know i can use something like

```
=MOD(ROW(A1),2)
```

down along the adjacent column, which puts a 1 or 0 in each row which i can then filter.

I wonder if there is a simpler method using a formula?

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I want to end up with this in another 2 columns.

```
A  A  B
B  C  D
C  E  F
D
E
F
```

I have tried `=OFFSET($A$2,2,-1)` in Column B1 and `=OFFSET($A$2,4,-1)` in cell B2, dragging down does not increment properly, i need to increment the "2" by 2 on each new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One formula.

Put this in B1 copy over and down.

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW($A1)-1)*2+COLUMN(A$1))
```

Unlike INDIRECT and OFFSET, this is not volatile.

[image]

Comment: this is a great answer, for simplicity it wins

Answer (score 1):

Use Indirect.

In B1 use this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(ROW(B1)*2-1))
```

In C1 use this formula

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(ROW(C1)*2))
```

Comment: yes perfect, Thanks Phil - I had used indirect in the past, had a sneaking suspicion it would work for this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a row count mulitplied by 2, into your OFFSET,

In B1 you can use:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)*2,0)
```

In C1 you can use:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)*2,0)
```

Then drag them both down.